# Is it possible to upgrade pip via text file?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Assume the machine has an older pip version - example pip 10.0.0

To update pip I use: `python -m pip install pip==20.1.1`

Is it possible to create a text file with freezed pip version - example - `pip == 20.1.1` and install it using `pip install -r file.txt`. Will all the packages in the file.txt then use the 20.1.1 pip? or will they still use the original pip 10.0.0?

Comment: Do you want to save all the packages frozen under this pip version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will all the packages in the file.txt then use the 20.1.1 pip?

No, they will use the original pip 10.0.0. The command `pip install -r requirements.txt` runs once under one `pip`. After the command starts the same Python and the same `pip` are running until the entire `requirements.txt` is processed.

So if you want to upgrade `pip` and immediately use it you need 2 (two) separate commands:

```
python -m pip install -U pip==20.1.1
pip install -r requirements.txt
```